# Is it "Pour quoi faire" or "Pour faire quoi"?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, questions, infinitif

I wrote the following sentence for my french class:

> Tu veux monter au sommet du mont Everest? Pour faire quoi?!

However, my teacher corrected it to say:

> Tu veux monter au sommet du mont Everest? Pour quoi faire?!

Why did she flip the positions of "quoi" and "faire"? I wanted the second sentence to say "To do what?!". But now it says "To what do?!", which doesn't make sense.

Did my teacher make a mistake or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Either one is possible. "Quoi" often works like a direct object pronoun, and those come before the verb. (Compare: "Pour le faire / Pour faire ça.") In this sentence, your teacher's sounds less informal. But I don't know enough to say anything more specific, so I'll leave the answering to someone else!

Comment: Is it common for words to be inverted like this so that the sentence sounds more casual? If so, in what cases can you invert words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cela peut s’analyser par ce qui est entendu et sous-entendu :

> Pour faire quoi [la-haut] ?
>
> Pour quoi faire  ? On entend « Pourquoi faire [cette ascension] ? »

Réponse subjective qui peut expliquer pourquoi le professeur a modifié l’ordre des mots : à part prendre une photo ou planter un drapeau, il n’y a pas beaucoup d’activités possibles sur le toit du monde.

Comment: In the whole range of disinterested human endeavors, at least from a material point of view , and specially in the domain of mountain climing, we are not much concerned with such practical matters. I do not think at all that we should here speak of abreviations of language. Consider a possible answer to the question: So as to experience the awe and grandeur associated with this part of nature, to experience the real feeling of it, a feeling  I know  to be familiar to all mountain climbers. I believe the teacher is just factual, not motivated by the context of an unconsequential assertion.

Comment: @user168676 — Même si je ne suis pas allé plus haut que https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiguille_du_Tour (côté Sud et il y a fort longtemps), je comprends votre réaction, celle d’un grimpeur confirmé. Vous parlez des perceptions, des émotions, donc des verbes d’état percevoir, sentir ; or la question est posée avec un verbe d’action. Si la personne ignore tout du monde alpin, ou si le connaissant, elle est sensible aux différences d’emplois des verbes d’état et d’action, sa subjectivité, ses "automatismes" peuvent facilement entrer en jeu et orienter l’ordre des mots de sa réponse. — …

Comment: @ cl-r Non, ma réaction n'est celle d'un grimpeur confirmé mais celle de quelqu'un qui la comprend tant soi peu. La category de verbes que vous mentionnez justement ne concerne que l'exemple particulier donné; un autre exemple aurait pu être « parce que je pense qu'il n'y a pas assez de français qui ait accomplit cela et que j'aimerais que la France soit mieux représentée. » et il y en a d'autres dans des domaines variés d'aspirations d'un niveau que l'on ne peut juger que comme étant élevé. Ce point de vue plus général qui est le mien rend votre question difficile, pas de place pour m'étendre

Comment: @ cl-r Le second commentaire de votre part qui vient de m'être adressé me laisse franchement dans le néant; j'avoue n'y rien comprendre, rien du tout.

Comment: @user168676 — Comme je l’ai écrit, ma réponse est subjective et reflète une réaction que j’ai analysée en fonction des usages que j’ai en tête. Ce n’est pas votre ressenti, et, en relisant votre premier commentaire je me suis aperçu que ma réponse est basée sur le mot *faire*. J’ai supprimé mon deuxième commentaire que je reformule ainsi : si le maître avait demandé : « Pour sentir/vivre/percevoir quoi ?» et ensuite « Pour quoi sentir/vivre/percevoir ? » il aurait posé une question sur l’alpinisme, l’ordre des mots *pour* et *quoi* n’a alors plus la même importance, …

Comment: @user168676 — … et l’on n’entendrait plus « *Pourquoi* sentir/vivre/percevoir », car ce n’est pas un contexte méta-physique. Chacun de nous a une lecture, une perception, une analyse différente de la langue, et cela est nécessaire pour refléter des sensibilités et des points de vue distincts… j’espère ainsi avoir compris le vôtre et mieux expliqué le mien.

Answer (score 2):

The essential aspect in deciding which is to be used, putting aside the fact that nowadays people tend to forget the difference between standard and substandard as   concerns those foms, is that "pour quoi faire?" remains more a factual question, free of insinuations, whereas "pour faire quoi " can be used by speakers in a rather abrupt manner, not quite polite, to the effect of notifying to the person to which it is intended a certain absurdity in the action they propose, or some such derogatory quality that the asker, rightly or not, imputes to it.

Comment: "Tu est venu à la plage pour chercher quoi?" (but never "Tu est venu à la plage pour quoi chercher ?") and the like of it shouldn't be overlooked, however it can be considered to be somewhat awkward (barely acceptable) and a better speaker will say instead "Qu'est-ce que tu est venu chercher à la plage?".

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the meaning of both expressions is exactly the same, the difference being just that "*pour quoi faire*" is a classical form and "*pour faire quoi*" a modern one. From a literary point of view, it is quite preferable to use "*pour quoi faire*", because it is a question so the pronoun has to be set before the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Bon!... on va commencer par affirmer que ta prof t'aura au minimum orienté vers [la forme la plus commune.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pour%20quoi%20faire%2Cpour%20faire%20quoi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpour%20quoi%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpour%20quoi%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPour%20quoi%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPOUR%20QUOI%20FAIRE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpour%20faire%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpour%20faire%20quoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPour%20faire%20quoi%3B%2Cc0)

Bon...! Cela ne veut pas non plus dire que la forme la moins fréquente soit pour autant fautive hein!

La construction de la phrase interrogative en français est matière à... longueurs! (une quarantaine de pages chez Grevisse (police de 2))...

Comme je ne vais te résumer tout ici, on va trier... hmmm :

Ton truc c'est d'abord : *Une interrogation **directe**.* (Bon parce qu'il y a aussi les *indirectes*)

Il s'agit ensuite d'une *interrogation **partielle***. (Bon... parce que dans les directes, il y a aussi les *globales*)

Et enfin... forcément... ces interrogations partielles... on peut les exprimer de façon plus ou moins soutenues.

Dans le langage soutenu, les interrogations partielles **commencent par l'interrogatif** : *Que fais-tu ? Quoi faire ? Que fait la police ?*

Dans le langage courant, on reporte l'**interrogatif en fin de phrase** :
*Tu fais quoi ? Pour faire quoi ? Cela fait quoi ?*

Bon... Tout ça pour dire... ma conclusion... t'as pas tort mais... c'est ta prof qui a raison. ;)

Bon... OK... ce n'était pas la peine de faire si long pour arriver à cette... banalité. ;)

Comment: Je n'ai pas compris. Vous avez d'abord dit que "pour quoi faire?" est la forme la plus commune, puis vois avez dit que "pour faire quoi?" est la forme plus courante. Y-a-t il aucune difference entre "commun" y "courant"?